# Magento 2.2.0 indexing update on scheduel is not working

Tags: magento-2.0, magento2.2.0

Magento 2.2.0 i have set index option update on scheduel. after i ran indexing command but it did not take effect.update on save working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your crontab is not setup right.

If you have SSH access could you go to the root folder of your Magento installation and execute the following command:

```
crontab -l
```

If it is empty install the Magento cron by running the following command:

```
php bin/magento cron:install
```

Now if you do a crontab -l again you will see a cronscript generated by Magento and the indexes should be updated every minute now !

Comment: cron is not setup but i am trying to run command php bin/magento indexer:reindex and that's also not work.

Comment: Cron is necessary for Magento to work fine so I suggest you install the cron and if you do a php bin/magento indexer:reindex you get an error back ?

Comment: i dont want to set cron. when i run command i am not getting any error. in latest magento if cron is not set till you can reindex by command and that's same process is not working in magento 2.2.0 version.